# Perform match if parameter is present in MongoAggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregation pipeline where i'd like to perform a match only if the intended params is present. For example;

`params = { fruit: 'apple', other_params.. }`

In my aggregation pipeline:

`Some.collection.aggregate([ { "$match": { fruit: params[:friut] } } ...other stages ])`

So I'd like to run match stage only if i have `fruit` in `params`. can it be done?

Note that `params` is not a collection but some external request parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb queries are javascript objects, so you can construct them easy and dynamically, with code, based on the params you got.

If you want all params to be part of the match you can do something like.

```js
Some.collection.aggregate([ { "$match": params } ...other stages ])

//params is variable that ou already have 
//params = { fruit: 'apple', other_params.. }
```

If you want some params to be part of the match you can do something like

```js
var matchQuery={};
if(params has "fruit") matchQuery["fruit"]=params["fruit"];
//.....you can do this for all the parameters.....

Some.collection.aggregate([ { "$match": matchQuery } ...other stages ])
```

Alternative instead of starting with `{}` you can remove from params the pairs that shouldnt be part of the matchQuery.

Comment: yes thats what i want to achieve but i was not able to comprehend your directions. perhaps an example would help?!

Comment: i tried to add some more, its not hard think of it a bit, you will do it, queries can be contructed with javascript, and use javascript variables

Answer (score 1):

You can realize this via simple $or logic in the match stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $match: {
   $or: [
    {
      fruit: {
        $exists: true,
        $eq: "apple"
      }
    },
    {
      fruit: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
])
```

explained:

1. If the key fruit exist it will check if is equal to "apple"
2. If the key do not exist it will not do anything

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Sw5t8bUXVb)

Comment: i reckon `$exist` may not be applicable in this case since we are not checking existence of `fruit` key in the document but its presence in request params. i have edited my question assuming you have got the context of question in a bit different way.

Comment: Why you need to check this inside the aggregation query ? You can check before the query and remove the $match stage if needed ?

Comment: to cut to the chase, i was not sure if that flexibility could be achieved inside the aggregation query. your suggestion helped. thanks, appreciate your time.